# HTML5's <video> tag on mobile browsers is render blocking

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, rendering, pagespeed-insights

We are using  tag for acting as an animated GIF replacement on our website(ucraft.com).

On the top screen of the page there is a background image, on which we have text and a call to action button.
After that there is another block of content, where we have a video on the left and text on the right...

After that block there are 2 other blocks with the same scenario:  tag and text.

On mobile(iOS and Chrome) the browser is waiting for the videos to autoplay, after which ONLY it shows the background image in the first(top) screen.

Thus Lighthouse is giving an issue that the rendering is not really well organized.

From the other hand, the UX on the website is bad, because the users don't really understand what to do, as the image is not being loaded(which is important) until the ALL videos of the page is loaded.

Due to this, Google's pagespeed gives us a grade of 30 for mobile, but 90 for desktop.

Please see the pagespeed result here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ucraft.com

Or you may also open the homepage on your device and see...

Here is the code we are using for the video:

```
<video  class="lazy" width="100%" height="100%" webkit-playsinline="true" autoplay muted playsinline="true" data-status="loaded" loop>
<source data-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ucraft.com/videos/domain-homepage.mp4">
<source data-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ucraft.com/videos/domain-homepage.webm">
</video>
```

And this code, that we are putting into the  to lazyload the video:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var lazyVideos = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("video.lazy"));
        lazyVideos.forEach(function(video){
            for (var source in video.children) {
                var videoSource = video.children[source];
                if (typeof videoSource.tagName === "string" && videoSource.tagName === "SOURCE") {
                    videoSource.src = videoSource.dataset.src;
                }
            }

            video.load();
            video.classList.remove("lazy");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Are we missing anything to tell browser to load everything, including the  tag and to show the poster, before the video is ready to play?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be using a background color, a background image, and then your video, in that order.  Users shouldn't have to wait for an image nor a video to be able to see some text.

Next, stop lazy-loading your video!  The browser already does a pretty good job of deferring video loads.  It's not your responsibility to change that.

Finally, there is no poster on your video.  Not sure if you intended to use one there or not, but since you mentioned it in your question, I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your points, it sounds like a plan! Will try this out and let you know!